# Docker - open /var/lib/docker/overlay2/xxx/merged/etc/passwd: no such file or directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, docker-build

I'm trying to 'docker build -t aspnetapp .'
But it stopped and shows error below.

```
=> ERROR [base 2/2] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                                            ------
 > [base 2/2] WORKDIR /app:
------
open /var/lib/docker/overlay2/702cb1f56ae4d4a7a5c14cf0db796842b47c7a237a02216dd59ac7bfd8044fca/merged/etc/passwd: no such file or directory
```

What I have tried:

- Removed DockerDesktop folder on C:\ProgramData
- Restarted Docker
- Uninstall and re-install Docker

Nothing works. Anyone has an idea to make this work?

Below is my Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-nanoserver-1903 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-nanoserver-1903 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["SampleCoreProject.csproj", "SampleCoreProject/"]
RUN dotnet restore "SampleCoreProject.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/SampleCoreProject"
RUN dotnet build "SampleCoreProject.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "SampleCoreProject.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SampleCoreProject.dll"]
```

Comment: Please include your entire Dockerfile

Comment: hi @tentative i have added my Dockerfile

Comment: Anyone can help?

Comment: Please add  the whole output to see what is happening at each stage and if in the publish stage the `/app/publish` is actually getting created

Comment: Does the `SampleCoreProject.csproj` and the `Dockerfile` are at the same folder ?

Comment: yes they are on the same folder @frank_lee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create a new project which the `.csproj` and `Dockerfile` are at same folder, and the `Dockerfile` is a little different from yours, try this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["SampleCoreProject.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./SampleCoreProject.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "SampleCoreProject.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "SampleCoreProject.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SampleCoreProject.dll"]
```

Comment: Hi @frank_lee I still get the same issue. I copy yours but still nothing changes.

Comment: I change the base image, please try again, thank you